# ¿Cómo acceder a la SD card en android?

Tags: android

Estoy probando hace un tiempo acceder a la SD card en distintos celulares. En algunos llegué a tener éxito, pero en otros no. Generalmente el problema es que el path o la ruta no es la misma para cada celular. Lo primero que encontré y probé es:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.getPath() + "ruta adicional hacia el archivo deseado");
```

Para el emulador esto me sirvió, pero no me sirvió con ningún otro celular. En alguno que otro conseguí llegar, pero necesito encontrar algo más genérico, o al menos alguna forma de poder encontrar la ruta para cualquier celular, relativamente rápido, si recibo un celular nuevo.

También encontré la posibilidad de hacer

```
System.getenv();
```

Que da varias opciones en forma de HashMap, pero las claves en los celulares que conseguí encontrar la ruta a las SD card no son las mismas ni tampoco las rutas.

Si puedo agregar algo que pueda ayudar avisenme.

** EDITADO
Mi problema es que tengo un archivo en una sd card y no lo estoy pudiendo encontrar en todos los celulares. Con cierto código accedo en la AVD, con otro en un celular, pero no encontré nada genérico para todos los celulares, e incluso hay celulares en las que no puedo encontrar el archivo.

Comment: En mi caso yo intentaba acceder a una BD en la SD y lo pude hacer así: public static final String DATABASE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/database.db"; No tengo mucho dominio de Android, mas bien estoy aprendiendo, pero a mi de esta forma me funcionó perfecto con el emulador y con 2 celulares más que probé.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta otra forma:

```
String SD_CARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
new File(SD_CARD_PATH + "/" + "fichero.ext");
```

Extraído de **[esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102104/android-how-to-access-a-file-in-the-sd-card)** respuesta de SO en inglés.

Aunque **[esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)** también te puede servir para entender. No agrego ejemplos de esta pregunta/respuesta porque no dan ejemplos. Más allá del código, se explica bien y detallado cómo Android gestiona los almacenamientos del dispositivo para que puedas entender mejor.

Comment: Voy a leer los links que pasás, pero por lo pronto intenté en unos celulares y me sirvió solo en el AVD. En otros dispositivos me trajo el mismo string (/storage/emulated/0), con lo que se ve como que Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() está hard codeado

Answer (score 1):

A mi este codigo me va perfecto:

```
    File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "nombreDelDirectorio");
     if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs(); //Si no existe lo crea
    }
    //Crea el archivo
    File file = new File(rootPath, "nombreDelArchivo");
```

Comment: Mi problema es que tengo en la memoria un archivo que quiero leer. Con ese código no puedo leerlo. Si bien ese código va a funcionar siempre, no siempre vas a estar accediendo a la verdaderia sdcard, sino quizá a un directorio del celular que no es la tarjeta